# Migrated a wordpress and the theme options does not work anymore

Tags: wordpress, themes

I just changed the archives of the wordpress from a file to the root of the server. In database I changed the lines with the old url. After this my configuration of the theme options didn't work anymore. I can see the code of theme_options in the wp_options table but I don't know what to do with this information.

Comment: The related database raws are 'template' and 'stylesheet'… see this related [**link**](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/change-theme-in-db). *(Check also your htaccess file)*

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand how this link can help me. I didn't change the template, I just changed my wordpress from the directory and the theme options of my theme is not working anymore. I can see the code of the configuration on the database in wp_options in theme_options_mentor (this last word is the name of my theme) but It's not calling.

Comment: The `template` key in database `options` table, is related to your theme,. You where asking for `theme_options` key, or not? and for `stylesheet` check the path or the data, is reared to your theme to.